# How to specify private nuget package source in msbuild 15.0 command line?

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Is it possible to specify private nuget feed server while using msbuild 15.0 in vs 2017?
The current powershell command I am using is following:

```
&$msbuild /t:restore /tv:15.0 /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
```

This is by default fetching only nuget.org's feed.

Comment: Yes it is resolved. Refer AjItH V S answer.

Comment: FYI, it's recommended you don't right now, and to use the CLI instead when using private feeds: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6609#issuecomment-369100145

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS Build reads  NuGet.Config files from the solution root. You can add a new Nuget.config file and specify the external repositories inside that.

[nuget.config reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#example-config-file)

Answer (score 17):

> How to specify private nuget package source in msbuild 15.0 command line?

If you want to restore the nuget package only from the specify private nuget package source, you could use the property `RestoreSources` to specify private source:

```
msbuild /t:restore /p:RestoreSources=xxx /tv:15.0 /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
```

Check the [restore target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-target) for some more details.

Comment: Multiple sources in `/p:RestoreSources=` have to be splitted with escaped version semicolon `;` -> `%3B`. For example, for `url1` and `url2`, `/p:RestoreSources=url1%3Burl2`

Answer (score 9):

you can use `/p:RestoreAdditionalProjectSources=…` to specify other sources.

Also, use `/restore` (MSBuild 15.3+) instead of specifying `Restore` together with other targets so all changed files generated by NuGet are properly reloaded.

Comment: Where the heck is this even documented?! All the hidden msbuild/nuget options are annoying to track down!

Comment: Did you mean `RestoreAdditionalProjectSources` instead of `p:RestoreSources` ?

Comment: yes, apparently I copied from a nuget issue that also had this wrong. edited.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets

Answer (score 0):

I added a new package source to nuget.config file located in '%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config' like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="anotherSource" value="http://10.2.36.4:53673/nuget" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```